# Will XeTeX or LuaTeX support COLR table in OpenType fonts?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, opentype

Announced at the Microsoft //build conference:

> A data structure, implemented as a new 'COLR' table in OpenType, breaks down the base glyph into a separate set of glyphs, each with its own z-order and single color reference. The color references are handled has palette indices, with a separate table, 'CPAL' in OpenType that resolves the RGBA colors actually used for the glyph.

Video here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-191

Original announcement on Typophile: http://typophile.com/node/104174

Comment: This is excellent! I hope everyone would adopt these new additions!

Comment: Sorry, but I believe this is off topic.

Comment: see the discussion here http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2013-August/024681.html

Comment: @egreg: Indeed. It's certainly not "a practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face". But questions with bounties can not be closed.

Comment: I'm with the other commenters: it's not a Q&A-answerable question.