# Character with two colors

Tags: color

I realise that this is somewhat of a special question, but is it possible to have regular characters in formulas, where the left half is colored e.g. in red and the right half is colored in blue, similar to the image below?

[image: Character with two colors as desired]

Comment: I once saw something similar in a german blogpost. This might already help you. [Zweifarbige Buchstaben (Two-colored letters)](http://tikz.de/zweifarbige-buchstaben/)

Comment: also this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192496/how-to-shade-text-in-different-colors

Comment: also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130806/will-xetex-or-luatex-support-colr-table-in-opentype-fonts

Comment: @dcmst, though very similar, but in this case OP needs bicolor letters in math-mode. Bearing in mind my limited knowledge about this topic, I don't know if it is possible to extend those answers to formulas.

Comment: @pouya the accepted answer there works for both math and normal text. But I'm not suggesting this is an exact dupe, just related.

Comment: (Not a duplicate. The question above requires a diagonal cut, this is a special case where the cut is vertical, so a special solution is applicable i.e. clipbox -- nevertheless it's true that all answers there can be ported here.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure what this would be used for, but the only method I see is to typeset two copies of the same glyph, clipped and differently colored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,xcolor}

\newcommand{\Atwo}{%
  \mbox{%
    \def\Ahalf##1{\dimexpr.5\width ##1 0.025em\relax}
    \textcolor{red}{\clipbox{0 0 {\Ahalf+} 0}{A}}%
    \textcolor{blue}{\clipbox{{\Ahalf-} 0 0 0}{A}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\Atwo
\end{document}
```

[image]

The little correction depends on the character: the vertex of the A doesn't lie at the exact half.

The risk of optical effects is very big: here the horizontal stem doesn't seem to connect properly, but just because of the choice of the colors.

Comment: What do you mean by optical effect? There actually is a bright line between the two colors, it's not just an optical illusion.

Comment: Probably an issue with the PDF viewer. There's no such issue in my case.

Answer (score 7):

Why not with `tikz` (I know for sure... it is heavy).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\Atwo}[3][A]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
      \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (a) {\phantom{#1}};
      \clip (a.south west) rectangle ($(a.north)-(0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$);
      \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=#2]  {#1};
    \end{scope}
    \clip (a.south east) rectangle ($(a.north)-(0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$);
      \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=#3]  {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\Atwo{blue}{red} \Atwo[B]{green}{magenta}
\end{document}
```

[image]