# Color lower half of the $\ge$ symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, color, stacking-symbols

I wish to partly change the color of the $\ge$ symbol. In particular, I want to change the horizontal bar into a red color, similar to this:

[image]

How can this be typset?

Comment: Here there is a starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201596/character-with-two-colors. Just for curiosity, but where have you seen this double coloured symbol?

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks, I'll look into it and try to make it work for my case. I actually haven't seen the symbol anywhere and just die a quick mockup in paint, I'm planning to use it in a formula sheet I'm working on and this marking would allow me to save space.

Comment: Ah, ok it seemed very strange to me because it's the first time I've seen a half-coloured symbol and I voted for you :-) I hope you get a response you like. My regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapting @egreg's (non-tikz) solution given in the link provided by @Sebastiano in the comments:

[image: ge symbol]

Fortunately, the bar portion of the glyph seems to be in the depth area, making the trimming for the clipbox viewport simpler.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,xcolor}

\newcommand{\skyge}{%
  \mbox{%
    $\ge$
    \textcolor{red}{$\ge$}%
    \llap{\textcolor{blue}{\clipbox*{0 0 {\width} {\height}}{$\ge$}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\skyge
\end{document}
```